# A fair die is rolled three times

Tags: probability

What is the probability that a two is rolled at least once with the condition that the third number is equal to the sum of the first and second?

I found $\frac{8}{15}$ as the answer, but I'm not sure.

Edit: My thought process was to find all the possibilities where the sum of the first and second roll are six or less.

$$(11,12,13,14,15,21,22,23,24,31,32,33,41,42,51)$$

This resulted in $15$ in total possibilities. $7$ of these possibilities included two rolls. Since the result of the $11$ rolls would result in a two we would have to add one to the possible outcomes, therefore, getting $\frac{8}{15}$

Comment: Share what exact thought process you used in order to get an answer of $8/15$

Comment: I have the same answer as you. Could you show us how you did?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure.

The quickest method to solve this is to just to count the equally-possible outcomes.

There are *fifteen* outcomes where the third die shows the sum of the first two die.   Five where the first shows `1`, four where the first shows `2`, three where the first shows `3`, two where the first shows `4`, and one where the first shows `5`.   $ (15=5+4+3+2+1)$

Among these *eight* outcomes show a `2` at least once.   One where the third die shows `2`, four where the second die shows `2`, four where the first shows `2`, but there is one where *both* the first and second show `2`.   $(8=1+4+4-1)$

Therefore the probability is $8/15$.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the correct answer has been posted. Just want to share my methods of calculation.

No of outcomes in which the sum of 2 dice equals to the third die is the no of integer solutions of $a+b+c=7$ which is ${6}\choose{2}$ $=15$.

No of outcomes in which first dice is 2 is no of integer solutions of $2+b+c=7$ which is ${4}\choose{1}$ $=4$

No of outcomes in which second dice is 2 is no of integer solutions of $a+2+c=7$ which is ${4}\choose{1}$ $=4$

No of outcomes in which first and second dice are 2 is no of integer solutions of $2+2+c=7$ which is ${2}\choose{0}$ $=1$

No of outcomes in which third dice is 2 is no of integer solutions of $2+c=7$ which is ${4}\choose{0}$ $=1$

Hence $\frac{4+4-1+1}{15}=\frac{8}{15}$

Comment: You should explain why the number of outcomes in which the sum of the outcomes on the first two dice equals the number on the third die is equal to the number of  solutions of the equation $a + b + c = 7$ in the positive integers.